# How to eliminate "BLANK" when the criteria does not meet using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to eliminate "BLANK" when the criteria does not meet? I'm trying to get count of rows with value greater than 0 else return nothing or 0 using DAX measure. I have negative values also in my column so just trying to count only above 0. Any suggestions? With below I can achieve count but if there are no rows meeting the criteria it returns "BLANK"

Measure=CALCULATE(COUNT('TableX'[column]),FILTER('TableX','TableX'[column]>0))

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a zero:

```
Measure =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( 'TableX'[column] ),
    FILTER ( 'TableX', 'TableX'[column] > 0 )
) + 0
```

You can also wrap the measure with the FORMAT function to output as text, which turns a blank into an empty string `""`.

```
Measure =
FORMAT (
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( 'TableX'[column] ),
        FILTER ( 'TableX', 'TableX'[column] > 0 )
    ),
    "0"
)
```

Use whatever [custom format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/custom-numeric-formats-for-the-format-function) you'd prefer to display the result as.

Comment: Thank you, It worked!! what if you do not want to show 0 in some scenarios it might look bad with 0 values just no value in the card?

Comment: You can display it as an empty string. See my edit.